# Copular modelo apenas com os dados do modelo no angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Atualmente estou fazendo uma requisição get no backend porém está retornando dados que eu não vou fazer uso, gostaria de copular meu modelo apenas com os dados que foram criados.

Meu modelo:

```
export class Cliente {

  public nome: string;
  public cnpj_rg: string;
  public cpf_inscricao: string;
  public email: string;
  public telefone: string;
  public sexo: string;
  public data_nascimento: string;
  public oferta_email: boolean;
  public informacoes_sms: boolean;

}
```

Minha requisição http:

```
  recuperaUsuario() : void {
    this.loadingService.alteraEstadoLoading(true)
    this.clienteService.recuperarCliente()
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe((res ) => {
      this.cliente = res.body;
      this.loadingService.alteraEstadoLoading(false)
    },
    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {

    })
  }
```

Meu serviço:

```
recuperarCliente() : Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<Cliente>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'clientes/dados-cadastrais', {observe: 'response'})
}
```

Meu problema é que meu backend está retornando mais chaves que o necessário e meu modelo acaba sendo copulado por elas me causando alguns problemas na hora de enviar esses dados pro backend.

Há alguma forma de eu copular apenas as chaves existentes no meu modelo?

Comment: vc tem que usar o operador map e mappear o objeto manualmente.

Comment: Você pode me prover um exemplo de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo:

```
recuperarCliente() : Observable<ClienteState> {//Gosto de usar state no final de entidades que contem o estado da aplicação
  return this.http.get<Cliente>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'clientes/dados-cadastrais').pipe(
           map(response => {
              return {
                name: response.name,
               ...etc
             }
           })
    ) // sem o state para entidades de payload do serviço do backend
}
```

vc tbm pode usar o delete pra remover apenas algumas chaves por exemplo:

```
delete response['propriedade'];
```

Comment: Entendi. Não tem uma forma de usar o modelo né? Eu gostaria não ter de digitar o nome de todas as chaves pois já digitei elas no modelo...